# How to run "has_secure_password" in condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rails 4. Then my model looks like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_secure_password

  def checkup?
    #Some Condition which returns true or false
    self.attr == "apple"
  end
end
```

In this i want `has_secure_password` run with the `checkup?` condition. i tried all bellow possible ways.

*Try 1*

```
has_secure_password :if => checkup?
```

*Try 2*

```
  def checkup?
    if condition_fails?
      has_secure_password  
    end
  end
```

Any Help?

Comment: what is your checkup?

Comment: assume it is `self.attr == "apple"`

Comment: Do you mean you want the digest created if checkup is true?  Or that you want the validations to run if checkup is true?

Comment: i want to run the validation only if checkup is true.

Answer (score 1):

So if you look at the source code via the docs.  You can pass validations: false to has secure password.  Then you simply need to reimplement them.

They are

```
validate do |record|
  record.errors.add(:password, :blank) unless record.password_digest.present?
end

validates_length_of :password, maximum: ActiveModel::SecurePassword::MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH_ALLOWED
validates_confirmation_of :password, allow_blank: true
```

So you end up with

```
class User
  has_secure_password(validations: false)
  validate do |record|
    record.errors.add(:password, :blank) if record.password_digest.blank? && checkup?
  end

  validates_length_of :password, maximum: ActiveModel::SecurePassword::MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH_ALLOWED, if: :checkup?
  validates_confirmation_of :password, allow_blank: true, if: :checkup?
end
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  and if so, what is a better way of accomplishing it?